# PreferenceFragmentCompat, crash with EditTextPreference

Tags: android, preference, edittextpreference

I have a settings XML file, implemented in a PreferenceFragmentCompat class. In the XML file, I have a "android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference" in a "android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen" like this :

```
android:key="@string/pref_key_code"
android:maxLines="1"
android:title="@string/pref_code_title"
```

When it was a simple "EditTextPreference" in a basic PreferenceScreen, this preference was working perfectly, but since I tried to change for v7.preference, it doesn't work anymore and I have this error when I click on it :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dialog view must contain an EditText with id @android:id/edit
    at android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onBindDialogView(EditTextPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onCreateDialog(PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:148)
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dialog view must contain an EditText with id @android:id/edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123715/dialog-view-must-contain-an-edittext-with-id-androidid-edit)

Comment: In deed, I saw it, but as he said, it's a "hack". I don't want a hack, there is a clean solution I think...